# Jquery, line break in textarea.. don't get \n and get ↵

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, textarea, line-breaks

I am trying to get value of a textarea with line break. When I debug, the value is this way in jquery. the value stored in a variable like this:

```
"test<br>
test<br>
test"<br>
In .value of valueOf is: 'test↵test↵test'.
```

I wonder how can I convert it to \n in order to insert line break.. I'm using jquery to get the value and send by ajax to php!
thanks.. :)
Sorry my english..

Comment: I think it would be better to store the text as is and then call nl2br() when needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
val=document.getElementById('recommend').value;
val = val.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/mg,"\n");
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eSub4/1/

I have put a couple of console.log in fiddle to show you how new line(\n) and html line break show up in console and compare it with the text from textarea to see that you are getting new line (\n) for text in textarea after using the regex. Keep firebug open to see the output

Comment: Thanks for the help .. Worked here ^^

Comment: @JhonatanG. If the solution has worked for you, can you up vote it and accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

try

```
document.getElementById('textareaid').innerHTML;
```

you need to replace 'textareaid' with the actual id.
since you say you already have the data in a string, but its not formatted right, to turn the `<br>` into newlines, you can use this

```
textString=textString.replace(/<br>/g,"\n");
```

Comment: Is returning an empty string :(

Comment: I changed the id. The innerHtml is returning empty.
I tried using the code of your edition but didn't work:(
My textarea code like this: <br>
<textarea name="recommend" wrap="hard" required="required" cols="30" rows="6" id="recommend"> </ textarea>
<br>.
 Thanks for the help ^ ^

Comment: innerHTML is case sensitive, so
`document.getElementById('recommend').innerHtml;` will not work you need `document.getElementById('recommend').innerHTML;` all letters in HTML must be capitalized!

Comment: I tried this but didn't work.
This is very strange.. I read on websites that the textarea has to add \n to line breaks.. :/

Comment: Thanks for the help .. Worked here ^^

Answer (score 0):

It works for me....

```
$("#id").val("<?php echo str_replace(array("\r\n","\r","\n","\\r","\\n","\\r\\n"),"<br>",$value); ?>".replace(/<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, "\n"));
```

Comment: Welcome to stack Overflow! Would you care to [edit] your answer to include an explanation how your answer differs/is better than the existing answers?